# genfromtxt in Python-3.5

Tags: numpy, python-3.5, genfromtxt

I am trying to fix a data set using genfromtxt in Python 3.5. But I keep getting the next error:

```
ndtype = np.dtype(dict(formats=ndtype, names=names))
TypeError: data type not understood
```

This is the code I'm using. Any help will be appreciated!

```
names = ["country", "year"]
names.extend(["col%i" % (idx+1) for idx in range(682)])
dtype = "S64,i4" + ",".join(["f18" for idx in range(682)])

dataset = np.genfromtxt(data_file, dtype=dtype, names=names, delimiter=",",  skip_header=1, autostrip=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

`dtype = "S64,i4" + ",".join(["f18" for idx in range(682)])`

is going to produce something like:

`s64,i4f18,f18,f18,f18...`

Note the lack of a comma after the i4.

Comment: I included the comma after i4, but still I'm getting the same error when I ran the next line of code where dataset is. Any other ideas? Thanks